# Fundamental group of wedge of two projective planes

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, projective-space

**Setup:**

Let $X = \mathbb{R} P^2 \times \left\lbrace 0, 1\right\rbrace/(p,0) \sim (p,1)$ with $p \in \mathbb{R} P^2$.

Compute the fundamental group of $X$.

**My solution**
First, we have that $X$ is path-connected since it is the image of the canonical projection of two path-connected space with one identified point.

Therefore, the fundamental group of $X$ is independant of the choice of base point $x_0$.

We take $x_0 =[(p,0)]$.

***Now, we use the Van Kampen theorem:***

Let $A = (B_r(p) \cup B_r(-p)) \cap S^2 \in S^2$.

Then, $\pi(A) = B_r(p)\cap \mathbb{R}P^2$  in $\mathbb{R} P^2$ with $p \in \pi(A)$ (with $\pi: S^2 \to \mathbb{R} P^2$).

Let us call that subspace  $B$

Now we consider $\pi: \mathbb{R} P^2 \times \left\lbrace 0, 1\right\rbrace \to X$ and let
$$U = \pi((\mathbb{R} P^2 \times \left\lbrace 0\right\rbrace \cup( B  \times \left\lbrace  1\right\rbrace))$$
$$V = \pi((B \times\left\lbrace 0\right\rbrace  )\cup( \mathbb{R} P^2 \times \left\lbrace 1\right\rbrace)$$
First, $U$ and $V$ are open by construction. Also, $U$ and $V$ path-connected.

We have that $B \approx B_{1}(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ the open ball and $\mathbb{R} P^2 \times \left\lbrace i\right\rbrace$ is path-connected being a product of path-connected spaces. For any pair of points separated in the domain, call them $(x,0)$ and $(y,1)$ we can define paths
$$\gamma_1:(x,0)\to (p,0)$$
$$\gamma_2:(p,1) \to (y,1)$$ and concatenante  them (since $(p,0) \sim (p,1)$) so that they are connected by a path in $X$.

We also have that $U \cap V$ is path connected by the same reasonning.

Hence, we can apply the Van Kampen theorem with those subspace.

**From here, I'm not sure how to proceed**

I would like to show that $U \cap B =\pi( B \times \left\lbrace 0,1) \right\rbrace \simeq \left\lbrace p \right\rbrace$

Ideally, I would show that if $B\times \left\lbrace i \right\rbrace$ can be retracted to a point and then I would have
\begin{align*}
\pi_1(U, p) = \pi_1(\mathbb{R}P_2, p) = \mathbb{Z}_2\\
\pi_1(V,p) = \pi_1(\mathbb{R}P_2, p) = \mathbb{Z}_2\\
\pi_1(U \cap V, p) = \pi_1(point) = \left\langle 1 \right\rangle
\end{align*}
and therefore
\begin{align*}
\pi(X, p) &= \left\langle a,b | a^2 = b^2 = 1\right\rangle\\
&\cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2
\end{align*}
But I can't seem to find a way to show that I can retract the set $B$ into the point.

Any help on how to proceed would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

*PS: I am sorry if my solution attempt is a bit confusing, English is not my first language and I'm new to that kind of proof!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@AndresMeija’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4424796/2439) points out the one error in your question.  On the other hand, regarding the one gap that you mention, showing that $U \cap V$ retracts to a point: follow the following steps:

1. $U \cap V$ is homeomorphic to the wedge $B  +_p B$;
2. for small $r$, $B$ is homeomorphic to $B_r$, which in turn is homeomorphic to an open disc (with $p$ corresponding to any point you choose);
3. so $U \cap V$ is homeomorphic to the wedge of two open discs;
4. the wedge of two open discs is contractible (glue the discs at their centres as the glued point; contract each disc radially in to its centre).

Comment: Thank you very much! Why do we want r small? Is it because we know that the projective plane is a surface?

Comment: @Ianatore: We need $r$ small enough that $B_r(p)$ and $B_r(-p)$ are disjoint in the sphere — that’s what will ensure $B_r(p)$ is homeo to its image in projective space.  (The exact value of $r$ depends on which metric you’re using on the sphere.)

Answer (score 2):

This is right up until the very end. $\pi_1(X)=\langle a,b \mid a^2=b^2=1\rangle$, but this is *not* $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$, this is $\mathbb Z_2 *\mathbb Z_2$, which is the *free* product of these groups.

The difference is that $aba^{-1}b^{-1}=1$ in $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$.